# How do i return a response as excel file using dropwizard?

Tags: excel, download, apache-poi, response, dropwizard

I am using dropwizard for my rest api development, which returns json response. I have now come across a requirement where i have to return a excel file on the call of the one particular api. I found out that apache poi is good library to use. But how do i return the excel file as response . The browser should then show a option to download.

Answer (score 9):

Set the Content-Type as `application/octet-stream` and add a `Content-Disposition` response header should do it. Something like `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xsl"`. For example

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public Response getFile() throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
        return Response.ok(is)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, 
                        "attachment; filename=\"file.txt\"")
                .build();
    }
}
```

Other than `InputStream`, you could return `File`, a `byte[]`, a `StreamingOutput`, you have options.